# R: Build up vector element by element

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to build a simple data structure in R and am failing terribly in trying to do so. My goal is to put together something that looks like this:

```
c("#E08214" = "#E08214", "#E08216" = "#E08216")
```

The purpose of the data structure is to help me manually assign the colors of each bar in a strange bar plot (the hex colors are identified in my dataframe, and I plan to use `scale_colour_manual(values = c("#E08214" = "#E08214", "#E08216" = "#E08216"))` to set each bar's color.

I can populate a list of my colors like so: `levels(df$color)`. I tried converting this list to a data structure like the one identified above by doing:

```
assignments = c()
for (color in levels(df$color)) {
  assignments <- c(color = color, assignments)
}
```

but this fails gloriously. Any help others might be able to provide on this question would be most appreciated.

Full code sample:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)

url <- 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/duhaime/5e06cb7d703dc818f06aa49da67ed13b/raw/1d597e4bf523d925ef3b9873e622c96d7877d347/pop.df'
df <- fread(url)
colnames(df) <- c('vid', 'frame.idx', 'box.idx', 'color', 'percent')

ggplot(df, aes(x=frame.idx, y=percent)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity', aes(fill='color')) +
  facet_wrap(~vid, ncol=1) +
  guides(fill=FALSE) +
  scale_fill_identity()
```

Comment: `scale_color_identity()` if the colors are really the RGB hash-prefixed strings. But, if you have a vector of colors, you can just `setNames()` them, too (if the names aren't the hex strings)

Comment: @hrbrmstr this is interesting but not evocations are coloring my bars. I think I actually need `scale_fill_identity()` as I'm using `geom_bar`, but I can't seem to get this going--I'm getting `Error in grDevices::col2rgb(colour, TRUE) : invalid color name 'color'` (my color names are hex values). Do ou have any notions on ways to resolve that?

Comment: `scale_fill_identity()` for `geom_bar()` that geom requires a fill aesthetic.

Comment: @hrbrmstr I'm trying that but am getting `grDevices::col2rgb(colour, TRUE) : invalid color name 'color'`. I added a full code sample. Is there a way to use `scale_fill_identity()` in this case?

Comment: use aes(fill=color), no quotes

Comment: Amen @GangeshDubey, thank you!

Comment: @hrbrmstr If you convert your comment to an answer I'll accept it, as I ended up using `scale_fill_identity()`, with h/t to @GangeshDubey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=frame.idx, y=percent, group=frame.idx, order=box.idx)) +
  geom_col(position="stack", aes(fill=color), size=0) +
  facet_wrap(~vid, ncol=1) +
  guides(fill=FALSE) +
  scale_fill_identity() +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major.x=element_blank())
```

[image]

I'm also fairly certain your data needs some work as does the visualization choice.

Comment: `position="fill"` might even be better but I rly don't know what you're trying to visualize.

Comment: @duhaime, you may want to clean data and particularly aggregate depending on your need before visualizing,in its current shape it hardly helps.

Comment: @GangeshDubey No doubt, I needed the visuals to help me clean! I ended up using three.js to do this, but am glad to be able to crank out quick charts with ggplot using this method

Comment: aye. i saw the project repo(s). looks like interesting work!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up `names(assignments) <- levels(df$color)` as well

so you can code as below

```
assignments <- levels(df$color)
names(assignments) <- assignments
```

OR the way you are currently doing

```
assignments = c()
for (color in levels(df$color)) {
  assignments <- c(color, assignments)
}

names(assignments) <- assignments
```